# CommandField ImageButtons to Render side by side

Tags: asp.net, gridview, alignment, imagebutton, commandfield

Cannot make Update and Cancel ImageButtons to render side by side in a GridView, they are always stacked on top of each other in this Edit CommandField no matter how wide I make the column:

```
<asp:CommandField ButtonType="Image" ShowEditButton="true" HeaderText="Edit" EditImageUrl="~/i/BlueButton.jpg" ControlStyle-CssClass="center-block"
    CancelImageUrl="~/i/Cancel.jpg" UpdateImageUrl="~/i/Update.jpg" >
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Height="25px" Width="100px" />
</asp:CommandField>
```

I tried many approaches in vain; for example, wrapping the commandfield in a div - failed, probably because I tried to do it inside the GridView; could not find a combination of alignment specifications that would work.

Comment: "center-block" likely sets `display: block` on some html elements which would make them break

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Martin! Solved simply by dropping ControlStyle-CssClass="center-block". Centering the controls is taken care of in ItemStyle.